# How to use HTTP Post method to return a file object

Tags: angular, http, typescript, post

How do I use a http POST request to return a file object. When I use the POST request to upload the file onto the server everything works as intended so I know that the file is saved and uncorrupted. However when I try to retrieve the file I get a weird response: [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpKig.png)

The last console output is what the file looks like when it gets uploaded to the server. The console entry above that shows the response that is returned when I try to grab a file from the server. Is the file corrupted?

This is my post request when uploading a new file to the server:

```
formData.append('username', localStorage.getItem('username'));
formData.append('subleaseISUcookie', localStorage.getItem('subleaseISUcookie'));
if(fileCount > 0){
  formData.append('fileName', inputEl.files[0]);
  console.log(inputEl.files[0]);
  this.http.post(URL, formData).subscribe(
          res => {
              //console.log(res);
               if(!res['error']){
        console.log("no error");
      } else {
        console.log(res['error']);
      }
         //this.router.navigate(['login']);
          },
          err => {
          console.log("there was an error");
      console.log(err);
          }
        );    
}
```

This is how I grab the file from the server:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ProfilePictureGrabService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  currUser: string = localStorage.getItem('username');

  requestString: string = '/retrieveProfilePicture/' + this.currUser;
  getProfilePic(): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.requestString);
    // Get the json data string
    return this.http.post( this.requestString , {
        username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
        subleaseISUcookie: localStorage.getItem('subleaseISUcookie')
    }).map(res => {

        return res;
    });
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

And lastly this is how I call the above service to use the file object returned by the http post request:

```
this.profilePictureGrabService.getProfilePic().subscribe( any => {
  this.retrievePic = any;
  console.log(this.retrievePic);
});

var reader2 = new FileReader();
this.profilePic = this.retrievePic;
if(this.profilePic){
  reader2.readAsDataURL(this.profilePic);
}else{
}
reader2.onload = function(){
    //localStorage.setItem('profPic', JSON.stringify(inputEl.files[0]));
    (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('profilePic')).src = reader2.result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    In your ProfilePictureGrabService class do,

    import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    @Injectable()
    export class ProfilePictureGrabService {
        headers: any;
        options: any
      constructor(private http: Http) {

           this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers }); 
         }

currUser: string = localStorage.getItem('username');

  requestString: string = '/retrieveProfilePicture/' + this.currUser;
  getProfilePic(): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.requestString);
    // Get the json data string
    return this.http.post( this.requestString , {
        username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
        subleaseISUcookie: localStorage.getItem('subleaseISUcookie')
    },this.options).map(res => {

        return res;
    });
  }
```